# Catching multiple exceptions and do same operations

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I am writing a transaction management system and catching 6 exception I need to rollback transaction for each exception. Now I am doing it in each block, is there a way to centeralized, i know one way is to throw exception from the method.

```
       catch (RollbackException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (HeuristicMixedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (HeuristicRollbackException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (SystemException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
        } catch (SystemException e) {
        if(log.isErrorEnabled())
        {
            log.error(e);
        }
        try {
            trans.rollback();
        } catch (RollbackException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (HeuristicMixedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (HeuristicRollbackException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (SystemException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    } catch (RollbackException e) {
       if(log.isErrorEnabled())
       {
           log.error(e);
       }
        try {
            trans.rollback();
        } catch (RollbackException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (HeuristicMixedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (HeuristicRollbackException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (SystemException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    } catch (HeuristicMixedException e) {
        if(log.isErrorEnabled())
        {
            log.error(e);
        }
        try {
            trans.rollback();
        } catch (RollbackException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (HeuristicMixedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (HeuristicRollbackException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (SystemException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    } catch (HeuristicRollbackException e) {
        if(log.isErrorEnabled())
        {
            log.error(e);
        }
        try {
            trans.rollback();
        } catch (RollbackException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (HeuristicMixedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (HeuristicRollbackException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        } catch (SystemException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Java 6 or 7?

Comment: You could probably `catch( Exception e )` and then do type checking. If it is not a type you expect, just remember to `throw;`

Comment: The first catch has no try?

Comment: Can you clean up your code in the question? I suspect you could let some exceptions escape, but I'm not sure why you have multiple rollbacks in your catch for rollbacks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java 7, you can pipe the exceptions in a single catch:

```
try {
    // code which can throw many kinds of exceptions
}
catch (FooException | BarException | BazException e) {
    // do the common thing!
}
```

Comment: Interesting. What is the type of `e` then? The closest super type? `Exception`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 7, you can reduce all of that to this:

```
try {
    ...
} catch(RollbackException|HeuristicMixedException|HeuristicRollbackException e) {
    if(log.isErrorEnabled()) {
        log.error(e);
    }

    try {
        trans.rollback()
    } catch(RollbackException|HeuristicMixedException|HeuristicRollbackException|SystemException e1) {
        e1.printStacktrace();
    }
}
```

If you are using Java 6, your options are limited. You *can* do `catch (Exception e)`, but that will catch any kind of exception, which is not what you want. So you will have to do `instanceof` checks to make sure that you have the right kind of exception and then `throw` the ones that don't match:

```
try {
    ...
} catch(Exception e) {
    if(e instanceof RollbackException ||
       e instanceof HeuristicMixedException ||
       e instanceof HeuristicRollbackException) {
        if(log.isErrorEnabled()) {
            log.error(e);
        }

        try {
            trans.rollback();
        } catch(Exception e1) {
            if(e1 instanceof RollbackException ||
               e1 instanceof HeuristicMixedException ||
               e1 instanceof HeuristicRollbackException ||
               e1 instanceof SystemException) {
                e1.printStacktrace();
            } else {
                throw e1;
            }
        }

    } else {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think about whether all of these exceptions are of the same type, and then, if they are, make them subclasses of a bigger superclass.

Edit: I've been informed that you didn't write those exceptions. For a roundabout way, you can use the fact that these are non-RuntimeExceptions (since they're checked exceptions). It's probably not a good habit, and I recommend you rethink your structure instead.

```
try{
    ...
catch(Exception e){
    if(e instanceof RuntimeException)
        throw e; //rethrow unexpected exception
    //do the right thing
}
```

---

As for restructuring your code, here are a few things I've noticed:

- Two of the exceptions thrown by [`commit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/transaction/Transaction.html#commit%28%29) are rollback exceptions that indicate that the transaction was rolled back.
- The [`rollback()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/transaction/Transaction.html#rollback%28%29) method doesn't throw any of those except `SystemException`.
- "The SystemException is thrown by the transaction manager to indicate that it has encountered an unexpected error condition that prevents future transaction services from proceeding." ([src](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/transaction/SystemException.html)) So you can't rollback after a `SystemException`.

If you catch an exception, it should be because you'll fix the problem it indicates (more generally, put the program back in a valid state), or you'll do something (like resource cleanup or logging) and *rethrow it*, or you'll stop the program.

Not knowing the specifics of what you're doing, I'd recommend:

- Don't catch the `SystemException` at this level. Let it go further.
- Catch the `RollbackException` and the `HeuristicRollbackException` and log them, but don't roll back.
- Catch the `HeuristicMixedException` and roll back.

We simplified the code, without even knowing how to catch multiple types of exceptions at the same spot. Using [Java 7's two enhancements to exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html), we can simplify further by doing what you want: catch multiple exceptions at one spot.

Here it is.

```
try{
    try{
        trans.commit();
    } catch (HeuristicMixedException e) {
        if(log.isErrorEnabled()){
            log.error(e);
        }
        trans.rollback(); //catch SystemException at another level
        //Note: We are now leaving this catch block as if
        //  the program state is okay again.
    } catch (RollbackException|HeuristicRollbackException e){
        if(log.isErrorEnabled()){
            log.error(e);
        }
        //don't need to rollback

        //Note: We are now leaving this catch block as if
        //  the program state is okay again.
    }
    //let SystemException propagate
}catch(SystemException e){
    //!do something
    //fix it or rethrow
}
```

Comment: These are Java EE exceptions so he won't be able to modify them.

Comment: @VivinPaliath Acknowledged. Still a generally useful strategy.